# Corona Admob plugin not working with other plugin

Tags: plugins, admob, share, coronasdk

I have a Corona application. If I am using both Admob and Share plugin its crashing in my device. If I use any one its working fine.
Here is the code of setting file

```
plugins =
    {
        ["plugin.google.play.services"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
        },
    },
    {
        ["CoronaProvider.native.popup.social"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
        },
    },
```

Is there anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Could you post more information? It's hard to figure out what the problem is just by looking at a part of build.settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. The code was wrong. It should like this.

```
plugins =
    {
        ["plugin.google.play.services"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
        },

        ["CoronaProvider.native.popup.social"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
        },
    },
```